# external mic plugged in + bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, audio, microphone, bluetooth-audio, audio-recording

Hopefully someone can help me.

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note II and I want to record with my external mic (rode smartlav+) but still listen to all audio from my phone via bluetooth. (Sena 20s).

### For example:

- All **outbound** audio -> Bluetooth device
- All **inbound** -> external mic

Is that possible?